# Getting an error when using a date parameter

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 5.0.1. I created a date parameter and am using it in my query:

[image]

When I preview the report, I enter my date parameter:

[image]

After I enter all the parameters and run the report, I get this error:

```
Error filling print... Error executing SQL statement for : Sample
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : Sample 
    at com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuter.createDatasource(PlSqlQueryExecuter.java:143) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1086) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:667)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1258) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745) 
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891) 
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572) 
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) 
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Feb" 
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1592) 
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1327) 
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:192) 
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:451) 
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:350) 
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254) 
    at com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuter.createDatasource(PlSqlQueryExecuter.java:136) 
    ... 12 more 
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

What is going on here, and how do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `!` in `$P!{...}` means to include the parameter's literal value in the report.

Try using `$P{start_date}` and `$P{end_date}`, both without the `!`.

Effectively, your SQL statement is using:

```
and finalinsdate >= Feb/18/2013
```

That is not a valid SQL statement, which means PostgreSQL will complain with:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Feb"
```

For next time, copy and paste the source code, instead of taking a screen capture.